# How to programmatically go to line / column in VS editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

What are the best practices when developing Visual Studio extensions to programmatically:

- Set focus on some file in some editor window?
- Set cursor on a specific line / column?

I have been searching for VS SDK documentation but I could not find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `I have been searching for VS SDK documentation but I could not find anything`, we help with specific issues and or problems you have tried to fix, currently this is not the case. If you update your post with what you have tried and where you are stuck we would be glad to help. Providing link only answers is off topic as well, please show us an attempt so we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To activate a file:

```
dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile(path, null);
```

To set cursor on a line/column:

```
EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = dte.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
ts.MoveToLineAndOffset(line, column);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergey! I guess now that operations to manipulate Visual Studio objects are described in the EnvDTE documentation. That's what I was looking behind. Great :-)